# why do I get "The requested resource could not be found." when accessing simple spray route?

Tags: scala, spray, spray-dsl

I tried a simple spray example app and i cannot access the route, I uploaded the example source code which does not work to github: [spray-tomcat-example](https://github.com/avidanyum/spray-tomcat-example):

```
 git clone https://github.com/avidanyum/spray-tomcat-example
 mvn package
 cp cp target/spray-tomcat-example-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ~/tmp/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/spraytomcat.war
 cd ~/tmp/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/bin
 ./catalina.sh jpda run
 http://localhost:8080/spraytomcat/
```

I get

```
"The requested resource could not be found."
```

I defined the route as following:

```
class ServiceActor extends Actor with Service {

  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}

trait Service extends HttpService {
  import com.example.domain.Person

  val myRoute =
    path("") {
      get {
        respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) {
          complete {
            <html>
              <body>
                <h1>Say hello to <i>spray-routing</i> on <i>tomcat</i>!</h1>
              </body>
            </html>
          }
        }
      }
    }


}
```

and ofcourse I have the `boot` class in place

in `application.conf`

```
spray.servlet {
  boot-class = "com.example.SprayBoot"
  request-timeout = 10s
}
```

and `SprayBoot` itself:

```
class SprayBoot extends WebBoot {

  val system = ActorSystem("actorsystem")
  val serviceActor = system.actorOf(Props[ServiceActor])

}
```

I'm pretty sure I followed all requirements am i missing something? how can I update it to actually serve the content instead of **"The requested resource could not be found."**

Comment: Try `pathSingleSlash` instead of `path("")`.

Comment: @jrudolph I just tried `pathSingleSlash` I get the same error also if i replace `path("")` with `path("/something")` then `/sprayexapmle/something` also didn't work for me...

Comment: The problem seems to be that spray isn't stripping of the context path. So ,you need to set `spray.servlet.root-path = "/spraytomcat"` setting to make it work. See at https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L37

Comment: @jrudolph I would be happy to mark it as answer if posted as answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @jrudolph said

> The problem seems to be that spray isn't stripping of the context
>   path. So ,you need to set spray.servlet.root-path = "/spraytomcat"
>   setting to make it work. See [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-servlet/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L37)

Answer (score 1):

The example will work when you deploy app into ROOT context without any extra configuration.

I've changed your script a bit:

`git clone https://github.com/avidanyum/spray-tomcat-example
 mvn package
 cp target/spray-tomcat-example-0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ~/tmp/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT.war
 cd ~/tmp/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/bin
 ./catalina.sh jpda run
 wget http://localhost:8080/`