# spray akka deployment on webserver

Tags: java, scala, akka, spray, xsbt-web-plugin

I have an application built on spray + akka. using this guide:

http://sysgears.com/articles/building-rest-service-with-scala/

It explains this example: https://github.com/oermolaev/simple-scala-rest-example

The application is working just fine. But when trying to deploy on a webServer I didn't find a way to do that.

I've tried to use xsbt-web-plugin to deploy on Tomcat, got the following input:

> ```
>  ~container:start
> ```
>
> [info] starting server ... Adding Context  for target/webapp ...
>
> Starting service Tomcat Starting Servlet Engine:
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
>
> getDefaultWebXmlFragment INFO: No global web.xml found
>
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>
> ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

But Tomcat is returning 404 for all the requests.

Does someone know how can I deploy a spray akka application on Tomcat?

Comment: See this question, there seems to be a problem with spray-servlet figuring out the context path on tomcat automatically, so you need to set it manually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701593/why-do-i-get-the-requested-resource-could-not-be-found-when-accessing-simple

Comment: Have you tried changing `spray.servlet.root-path` in your `application.conf`?

Comment: yes, it helped, thanks. my problem now is what to define  as <servlet-class> in the web.xml

Comment: @griffonvulture - can I ask why you want to deploy Spray on a web server (container)? Spray itself is containerless and can be deployed as a runnable jar file. Have you considered that option ? You can also redirect your traffic from the web-server to the Spray instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

This is what you need to make xsbt-plugin work with the spray application:

1. Set the `root-path` in application.conf

As @jrudolph pointed: spray servlet doesn't know to figure it out automaticly on tomcat:

```
spray.servlet {
   boot-class = "com.sysgears.example.boot.Boot"
   root-path = "/rest"
   request-timeout = 10s
 }
```

2. Change class `boot` to extend `webBoot`:

boot.scala

```
class Boot extends WebBoot {
  // create an actor system for application

  val system = ActorSystem("rest-service-example")

  // create and start rest service actor

  val serviceActor = system.actorOf(Props[RestServiceActor], "rest-endpoint")
}
```

3. add the web.xml as explained on xsbt-web-plugin:

   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

   ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>spray.servlet.Initializer</listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>SprayConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>spray.servlet.Servlet30ConnectorServlet</servlet-class>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>SprayConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

For the full change see the comparison on github (The example writer has generously generate this branch for tomcat users)

https://github.com/oermolaev/simple-scala-rest-example/compare/spray-tomcat

Comment: The example is long outdated, though. Maybe you should try setting up your application from the "official" template at https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_jetty_1.3_scala-2.11 which already contains all these files and also uses the latest version of spray :)